# IIS 7.5 + PHP + httpOnlyCookies + requireSSL

Tags: cookies, iis

How do I enable the httpOnlyCookies and requireSSL for all the cookie in IIS 7.5 ?

I have tried adding

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

within the

```
<system.webServer>
```

but it show 500 Internal Error.

Comment: Look like it should set these setting in PHP instead of IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the php.ini and find the line:

> session.cookie_httponly =

Set this value to true (e.g. to 1 as I have had issues with true for some reason) and restart IIS once you're done editing the php.ini.